# cocos2d sprite tag not being set

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, sprite

I'm using the following to create sprites with b2bodys
but I cant get the sprites tag to set. why isn't [sprite setTag:3];  working?

When I detect a collision with one of these sprites it says the sprite tag is 0

```
     -(void) addNewSpriteAtPosition:(CGPoint)p
     {
     // CCLOG(@"Add sprite %0.2f x %02.f",p.x,p.y);
// Define the dynamic body.
//Set up a 1m squared box in the physics world
b2BodyDef bodyDef;
bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
bodyDef.position.Set(p.x/PTM_RATIO, p.y/PTM_RATIO);
b2Body *body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

// Define another box shape for our dynamic body.
b2PolygonShape dynamicBox;
dynamicBox.SetAsBox(.5f, .5f);//These are mid points for our 1m box

// Define the dynamic body fixture.
b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
fixtureDef.shape = &dynamicBox; 
fixtureDef.density = 2;
fixtureDef.friction = 0.2f;
body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);


CCNode *parent = [self getChildByTag:kTagParentNode];

//We have a 64x64 sprite sheet with 4 different 32x32 images.  The following code is
//just randomly picking one of the images
int idx = (CCRANDOM_0_1() > .5 ? 0:1);
int idy = (CCRANDOM_0_1() > .5 ? 0:1);
CCPhysicsSprite *sprite = [CCPhysicsSprite spriteWithTexture:spriteTexture_ rect:CGRectMake(32 * idx,32 * idy,32,32)];

[parent addChild:sprite];

[sprite setPTMRatio:PTM_RATIO];
[sprite setB2Body:body];
[sprite setPosition: ccp( p.x, p.y)];
     [sprite setTag:3];
     }
```

Comment: Does something happen when the setTag line executes, or are you unable to retrieve sprites by tag? If it's the latter, post the code how you try to access the sprite by tag.

Comment: Yeah my problem is when I try to access it later. I am checking the tag in the collision event like this: 

          b2Body *bodyB = contact.fixtureB->GetBody();
          CCSprite *spriteB = (CCSprite *) bodyB->GetUserData();
          NSLog(@"tag: %d",spriteB.tag);

Comment: check the tag right after setting it. I'm sure it will be correct.